# Convert a file stream to a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have got an API that responds with audio/video files in forms of stream.

For e.g. a typical response looks like this:
`data:audio/mpeg;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBA...`

I use axios to call this API and get the raw stream data successfully. How do I convert this data into an usable file and also make this downloadable from the front-end?

P.S. Using React for the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anchor element, add **download** attribute and take the data as **href**. For example:

```
<a download='hello-world.txt' href="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=">Download Data</a>
```

This trick also works:

```
const downloadData = (filename, dataURI) => {
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    a.setAttribute('href', dataURI)
    a.setAttribute('download', filename)
    a.click()
    a.remove()
}

downloadData("hello-world", "data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=")
```